# what is the purpose of variable i minus 1 within the swap method? Is - 1 really necessary for a fair randomization?

Tags: java, algorithm, random, collections

I saw this code in Oracle documentation.

The documentation states: "The shuffle method below,unlike most naive attempts at shuffling, it's fair (all permutations occur with equal likelihood, assuming an unbiased source of randomness)".

My question is what is the purpose of variable i minus 1 within the swap method? Is - 1 really necessary for a fair randomization?

```
public static void shuffle(List<?> list, Random rnd) {
    for (int i = list.size(); i > 1; i--)
        swap(list, i - 1, rnd.nextInt(i));
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The indexing of the array goes from 0 to its size minus 1. Because the i starts at list.size(), which is 1 more than the index of the last element, and ends at index 2, subtracting 1 from i is required. The other option is to have

```
 public static void shuffle(List<?> list, Random rnd) {
    for (int i = list.size() - 1; i > 0; i--)
        swap(list, i, rnd.nextInt(i+1));
}
```

Comment: That should be: `swap(list, i, rnd.nextInt(i + 1));` otherwise you would never swap an entry to the last element in the list, and that would mean it's not a fair shuffle function.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Oh, yes, you are correct, I forgot to change that. Anyway, I edited it.

Comment: Note regarding Oracle's comment about "fair randomization": Notice that sometimes nothing will be swapped, because the two indexes passed to swap() will be the same.  The "naive attempts" they mention don't allow those indexes to be the same, so they always swap, and don't produce fair random permutations

Comment: @MattTimmermans Yeah, if it is without that correction (the i+1 one), no element will be at its starting position.

Answer (score 2):

Examine the problem with a list of size 10 for example. If you remove the `- 1`, then the first `swap()` to occur will run:

```
swap(list, 10, rnd.nextInt(10);
```

As there is only 10 items in the list, and you are trying to swap item 11 (due to list indexes starting at zero), the swap will fail.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is necessary because the list you are running through is 0 based, but the random function you are calling is not (the ceiling you pass in indicates the number of integers you want, so if you input 10 then the range of values returned is 0 through 9).

If the list has 10 items in it, then the index range is 0 to 9, when you generate a random number, you need 10 numbers so the numbers it will return are 0 to 9.

Comment: This is not correct.  rnd.nextInt(i) returns a number from 0 to i-1

Comment: You're right. Too much river water. I will correct that last bit